# SQL to LINQ - Rolling months of dates

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Wish to convert this to LINQ.

```
select COUNT(*) as 'BillsOver30' from pssuite_web.pujhaccd 
where billdays>30 and DATEDIFF(month,'07-07-2016', GETDATE()) <= 13
Group By Month(billdate)
```

This will show 13 rolling months from 07-07 with how many bills were over 30 for each month.

This is the terrible query I've written in LINQ, which doesn't work:

```
 DateTime earliestDate = objdate1.DateStart.Value.AddMonths(-13);
 var custQuery9 = ((from m in DataContext.pujhaccds
                    where m.billdays > 30
                    && m.billdate >= earliestDate
                    && m.billdate <= objdate1.DateStart
                    group m by m.billdays into p
                    select p)).Count();
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" how? Throws an error, no results, wrong results …?

Comment: Wrong results. I only get 1 result. I would want: July - 100, June - 200, May - 182 - for the 13 months.

Comment: Shouldn't that sql be `Select billdate, Count(*) as 'BillsOver10'`?  Otherwise you just get a set of counts without know which group they are in.  Also why is there a hard coded date in the `DateDiff` instead of presumably `billdate`?

Comment: You're grouping by `billdays` rather than `Month(billdate)`

Comment: Along with the wrong grouping, you're also doing a count of the number of groups instead of a count for each group, so instead you want `select p.Count()`

Comment: juharr, that's an example for if the user choose the date, 07-07-2016. If he chose 01-01-2016, the 13 months displayed will begin from that date. That's what objdate1.DateStart is; user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get result as you described in comments:

```
var result = (from m in DataContext.pujhaccds 
              where m.billdays > 30 && 
                  m.billdate >= earliestDate && 
                  m.billdate <= objdate1.DateStart 
              group m by m.billdate.Month into p   
              select new { Month = p.Key, Count = p.Count() }).ToList();
```

To get it like in original question replace the `select` above like this:

```
select p.Count()
```

That grouping will be problematic though if you have data from different years and want to separate it. If that is the case group by 2 fields - year and month:

```
var result = (from m in DataContext.pujhaccds 
              where m.billdays > 30 && 
                  m.billdate >= earliestDate && 
                  m.billdate <= objdate1.DateStart 
              group m by new { m.billdate.Value.Month, m.billdate.Value.Year }  into p   
              select new { Date = $"{p.Key.Month} - {p.Key.Year}", Count = p.Count() }).ToList();
```

Comment: Yeah, I will have data from different years as well. How would you group both?

Comment: @StemStep - check my edit (and also tell me if second option works - couldn't test it, not next to computer)

Comment: @StemStep - ok tested and works. Second format will result in values like "August-2016"

Comment: Method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL

Comment: @StemStep - ah ok ... it is executed in the database.... that is why... true.. Then just use the grouping with the 2 columns - Just undated it to not do the `ToString(string)`

Comment: Hey @GiladGreen , sorry for the delay. it did not work.  group m by m.billdate.Value.Month into p - works, adding {} makes it fail.

Comment: @StemStep - no problem :) just let me know if you need something

Comment: The working query:             var custQuery9 = (from m in DataContext.pujhaccds
                              where m.billdays > 30 &&
                                  m.billdate >= earliestDate &&
                                  m.billdate <= objdate1.DateStart
                              group m by m.billdate.Value.Month into p
                              select new Date1()
                              {
                                  theMonth = p.Key,
                                  theCount = p.Count()
                              });

Comment: Think you know a way to get the year to display with the month? Or at least order by the date it began with.

Comment: @StemStep - ya - afterwards for the `select` concatenate the 2 parts of the string - and you can then add `OrderBy(/*The field with the date parts*/)`

Comment: @StemStep - Great :) happy it helped!

Comment: Bah, it still puts all August 2016 and 2015 records into August 2015.

Comment: @StemStep - If you group by the two different fields, both year and month, then it isn't possible. Please then check your data and slowly debug

Comment: Oh, you're correct. It's working! Thank you for the help and your patience. I wish I could give you more rep.

Comment: @StemStep - haha :) just if I help you for next question you can upvote there too haha